Which faces does "sphere" lattice polyhedron $\operatorname{hull}(p\in\mathbb{Z}^3, \operatorname{norml}2(p)==n)$ for $n\neq4^a(8b+7)$ have?
$\operatorname{hull}(p\in\mathbb{Z}^3, \operatorname{norml}2(p)==n)$ for $n\neq 4^a(8b+7)$ is a lattice polyhedron.
By Legendre's three-square theorem, such $n$ have representation(s) as the sum of $3$ squares.
I created a small JSCAD script that allows you to vary $n$ in the range of $3..100$ in your browser:
lattice_sphere.html
Here with default value $n=42$ (because of Hitchhikers guide):

It is clear that the number of faces $F=E+2-V$ for $E$ edges and $V$ vertices.
What can be said of the face distribution for a given $n$?
For $n=42$ I see six 8-gons, and many 6-gons, 4-gons and triangles.
Is there some formula $c(n,k)$ for the number of k-gons for lattice sphere for $n$?
P.S:
I did count the JSCAD models for $n=3..6,8..14$, there are

triangles: $0,0,0,8,-,8,56,8,8,0,48,0$
4-gons: $6,12,6,18,-,6,0,42,18,6,6,12$

In addition

twelve 6-gons for $n=12$
eight 6-gons for $n=5,14$
six 8-gons for $n=14$.

I looked up "12 6 18 6 42" in oeis.org, but no hits.
P.P.S:
I created new JSCAD app that outputs analysis of face counts in browser console:
https://hermann-sw.github.io/lattice_sphere_cmp
From that app output I had to correct few numbers above (where I counted wrong before).
New JSCAD app allows to select either "≤ n" (for this question) or "= n" (because there are less points in hull and perhaps question is easier in this case).
I have seen all face lengths but 11 in range $3..12$.
This is example of maximal face length 12  (for "≤ n" with $n=80$) — the first such face is logged.

For all $12$ points of largest face reported $y=8$, so it is easy to see that they are in same plane.
There are two 2-tuples with sum of squares $≤ 80-8² = 16$ on convex hull face.
[2,3] gives 4 possibilities with different signs, [3,2] another 4.
And [4,0] gives 2, [0,4] another 2, in total 12.
Convex hull face length 12 happens for "= n" as well, first for $n=61$:
jscadMain with params Object { n: 61, cmp: "= n" }
4-gons: 24
6-gons: 8
12-gons: 6
ok
first max length face: [[6,4,-3],[6,5,0],[6,4,3],[6,3,4],[6,0,5],[6,-3,4],[6,-4,3],[6,-5,0],[6,-4,-3],[6,-3,-4],[6,0,-5],[6,3,-4]]
Main execution: 13.00 , jscad mesh -> gl: 0.00

If you open lattice_sphere_cmp.html, "≤ n" with $n=96$ is displayed as default.
I found that one interesting as it contains 9-gons despite all the symmetries of $x²+y²+z²$ ...
jscadMain with params Object { n: 96, cmp: "≤ n" }
Main execution: 223.00 , jscad mesh -> gl: 4.00 main.js:190:12
3-gons: 120
4-gons: 24
8-gons: 18
9-gons: 8
ok
first max length face: [[-3,7,-6],[-3,6,-7],[-4,4,-8],[-6,3,-7],[-7,3,-6],[-8,4,-4],[-7,6,-3],[-6,7,-3],[-4,8,-4]]
Main execution: 57.00 , jscad mesh -> gl: 0.00

P.P.P.S:
JSCAD app got new "= pq" compare function for semiprimes with $p,q=1 (mod 4)$ less $100$:
https://hermann-sw.github.io/lattice_sphere_cmp
Those semiprimes have few sum of two squares representations as well.
They are located on intersection of $x=0$ or $y=0$ or $z=0$ planes with lattice sphere.
Now 18-gon shows for $pq=53*97$, and 7-gon for $pq=89*97$.
(knowing two different sum of two squares representations of $n=pq$ allows to easily factor $n$)


Here's a MathJax tutorial :)

Thanks, I did MathJax edits, and added P.S.

I added P.P.S above with new lattice_sphere_cmp.html JSCAD app and description. Largest face length of hull for n=3..100 is 12, there exist 9-gons as well ...
